# Unity Custom Editor window - Multi-Selection Dropdown

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am currently working on a custom editor window in Unity3D(c#). Currently I'm trying to add a dropdown that allows for multiple selection.
[image: Dropdown Example]
This works, but the dropdown is limited to 32 items. I know this is because of Binary Encoding (32 bits and all) and see no direct way to work around this.

Do any of you know of another dropdown that allows for the same kind of multi-selection? (also including the "Nothing & Everything" options), or have any idea on how to write this dropdown myself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 32 items are way too many for a drop down menu.

You can create a fixed-height listbox with a scrollbar in a floating window instead. You will need to implement the logic of flag mask yourself.

A possible implementation of listbox: use `EditorGUILayout.Begin/EndVertical` and place buttons/toggles inside.

It's something similar to this:
[image]

As for floating window, see [PopupWindow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PopupWindow.html) and [EditorWindow.ShowAsDropDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.ShowAsDropDown.html).

Comment: Hello zwcloud, 

Thank you for the idea! I will definitely try this.